# Finding surface parameterization of a cylinder?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

I am new to multivariable calculus and am just get my head around the parameterization of surfaces. After research I found that a cylinder entered on the z - axis with radius R has a parameterisation 
$C(\theta, z) = Rcos\theta i + Rsin\theta j + z k $

But, what I don't understand is how this parameterization is derived in the first place. Like what is the method to arrive at that. I researched on several websites, including Khan Academy, but couldn't understand. Please help.

Comment: You have to have some background knowledge about vectors. $i,j,k$ in the parametrization are three such vectors, and if you know the visual representation of adding vectors, you'd see, quite easily I'd suspect, how the parametrization forms the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate pairs
$$
(x,y) = (R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta) 
$$
describe the points on a circle with center at the origin and radius $R$,
see e.g. the [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) construction, for a constant radius $R$.

If you then add a variable $z$ coordinate you get all such circles along the $z$-axis. 
$$
(x,y, z) = (R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta, z) \quad (z = \text{const})
$$
These circles form the cylinder surface. If $z$ is unbound it is a cylinder of infinite length, if $z \in [a,b]$ for real $a, b$ it is a finite cylinder.

Usually one adds the top and bottom discs for a finite cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for you:

As the cylinder has center on the $\;z\,-$ axis, if we "cut" the cylinder with the plane $\;z=0\;$ (the $\;xy\,-$ plane), then we get a circle $\;C:\;x^2+y^2=R^2\;$ , which is easily parametrizable by

$$C:\;r(\theta):=(R\cos\theta,\,R\sin\theta,\,0)\;$$

Now, just *repeat* the above argument for **any plane** of the form $\;z=k\;,\;\;k\;$ a constant (this means: a plane parallel to the $\;xy\,-$ plane) , and you'll get with that cut a circle $\;C':\;(R\cos\theta,\,R\sin\theta,\,k)\;$ .

From the above it is easily seen, imo, why the given cylinder has the parametrization it has.